# Paint different color above/ below zero in Chart

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I'm having trouble with a Windows form.  The data is in one series.

How can I paint the bar colors if above or below Zero?

```
int gtzero = this.Chart1.Series[0].Points
if (gtzero -gt 0)
{
  this.chart1.Series[0].Color = 'Green'
else
{
  this.chart1.Series[0].Color = 'crimson'
}
```

[image]

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: C# will get me there!
Thank you

Comment: I feel like Im missing a foreach statement?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach (var point in this.chart1.Series[0].Points)
{
    if (point.YValues[0] > 0)
    {
        point.Color = Color.Blue;
    }
    else
    {
        point.Color = Color.Green;
    }
}
```